# Why is Dispose being called, if my object was never constructed?

Tags: c#, dispose

Based on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/10/howtodisposemembersfromforms.aspx), I created a bridge between components for Windows forms and IDisposable objects. It pretty much looks like this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Disposer: Component
    {
        private readonly Action<bool> _dispose;

        public Disposer(Action<bool> disposeCallback)
        {
            if (disposeCallback == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(disposeCallback));

            this._dispose = disposeCallback;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            this._dispose(disposing);
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. Then I created unit tests, including one for the particular validation on the constructor argument.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void Disposer_ShouldNotAllowNullActions()
{
    new Disposer(null);
}
```

Here's the catch: not only my test fails, but it actually gets aborted. The test platform itself crashes (ReSharper test runner). By digging into my Windows Event Viewer I could see that the Dispose() method is being called, and since `this._dispose` is essentially null at this point, it fails with a `NullReferenceException`.

I fixed this with providing an empty lambda as the default value.

But if the constructor throws an exception (which I confirmed it does), why is the `Dispose` method called at all?

Comment: What if the constructor has already acquired some disposable resources before the exception is thrown? Those resources still need to be freed.

Comment: What's the purpose of having some delegate that gets called when the object is disposed?  What's the use case?

Comment: @DStanley IDisposable can be instantiated in a form but you will want to dispose them when the form is actually disposed (not closed). Dispose is already overridden in the form generated code, so the way to hook into it is by registering a component. (I didn't feel comfortable with moving generated code around.)

Comment: @Alpha I understand that; what I'm asking is why are you taking in a delegate that is called when the component is disposed?  `Component` already has a `Disposed` event that you can hook to.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Yes, agreed. Still, this is meant to be used with non-dynamic actions, but direct references to methods or hardcoded lambdas. The null check is just a safe-guard, but should not really be met. Aside from this, the particular behavior is what caught my curiosity.

Comment: @DStanley Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the `Dispose` method called at all?

The finalizer for a class is called even if the constructor throws an exception.  The [finalizer for `Component`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs.html#053ea5fbb05453a0) calls `Dispose()`:

```
    ~Component() {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

Since you override `Dispose(bool)`, your override is called if the constructor throws an exception.  Since this is a real possibility in your code, I'd suggest making sure both `this` and `this._dispose` are not null.

Answer (score 6):

The `Component` class must have a finalizer that calls `this.Dispose()`, which causes your override to be called.

Finalizers are run even if the constructor did not complete - this allows all resources that were allocated before the constructor failed to be cleaned up.